# moment-timezone.js doing wrong conversion

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to convert from one timezone to another (manually) getting a Date object and returning another by this function:

```
 getDateInMomentFormatToSave: function (date) {
                function padNums(num) {
                    return num.toString().length == 1 ? "0" + num : num;
                }
                var month = padNums(date.getMonth() + 1);
                var day = padNums(date.getDate());
                var hour = padNums(date.getHours());
                var minutes = padNums(date.getMinutes());
                var result = moment(date.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minutes, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
                var sourceMoment = moment.tz(result, "America/Mexico_City"); //UTC neutro de la BD moment.tz.guess()
                var localMoment = sourceMoment.clone().tz("Europe/Lisbon").format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss');
                return new Date(localMoment.substring(0, 19));
            }
```

One example case is:

- Date date = Fri Aug 17 2018 14:36:25 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)
- Moment sourceMoment = "2018-08-17 14:36" Moment
- localMoment = "2018-08-17T13:36:00"

Why is Mexico -> Lisbon only one hour ahead? As I know localmoment should be "2018-08-17T20:36:00".

What am I doing wrong? This seems to work for Europe/Lisbon to Europe/Madrid but I don't know why.

Thanks.

Solution:

```
var result = moment.tz(date.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minutes, "America/Mexico_City");
var localMoment = result.clone().tz("Europe/Lisbon").format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: I don't know why but calling .tz in moment initialization fixes the problem:

var result = moment.tz(date.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minutes, "America/Mexico_City");
            var localMoment = result.clone().tz("Europe/Lisbon").format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Date` object can *never* represent time in an arbitrary time zone.  It internally tracks milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  The functions that show non-UTC time are always converting between UTC and the *local* time zone of the machine where the code is executing.  Any attempt to return a `Date` object that is in some other time zone will ultimately fail, whether you're using moment to manipulate things or some other technique, because you can't get around the behaviors of the local time zone.

Also, when working with Moment, you shouldn't be doing so much manual manipulation of inputs and outputs, such as the string you're manually creating from date parts and then parsing again.  Moment can handle those things for you.

You can use a `Date` object as an input when constructing a `moment` object, but that would be for converting from the UTC instant being kept by the `Date` object.  You can construct a `Date` object from local time or from UTC time, but not from an arbitrary time zone.  Thus you cannot assert `America/Mexico_City` as the input time zone if your source is a `Date` object.   Instead, you could pass a string, an array, integers with individual parts, or any of the other methods of creating a `moment` object described in the documentation.

Likewise, you can never *output* a `Date` object if you want it to reflect an arbitrary time zone.  While moment does have a `.toDate()` function, it will be constructed based on the moment's UTC time (due to the limitations of a `Date` object).  In other words, code like `moment(someDateObject).tz(someTimeZone).toDate()` will just result in the same `someDateObject` you started with - regardless of the time zone passed.

Code to convert from one time zone to another using strings is like this:

```
moment.tz("2018-08-17 14:36:25", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", "America/Mexico_City")
      .tz("Europe/Lisbon").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")

//=> "2018-08-17 20:36:25"
```

The same code using arrays is like this:

```
moment.tz([2018, 7, 17, 14, 36, 25, 0], "America/Mexico_City")
      .tz("Europe/Lisbon").toArray()

//=> [2018, 7, 17, 20, 36, 25, 0]   (note months are 0-11)
```

But now see if we use `Date` objects, how that doesn't work:

```
moment.tz(new Date(2018, 7, 17, 14, 36, 25, 0), "America/Mexico_City")
      .tz("Europe/Lisbon").toDate()

//=> Fri Aug 17 2018 14:36:25 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Because *my* computer is in Pacific time, the input date is treated as Pacific (not Mexico City), and the output date is displayed as Pacific time (not Lisbon).   Even if I were to try to adjust the time to match some other time zone, it would still show `GMT-0700` and `Pacific Daylight Time`.  More importantly, it would still use the DST transitions between Pacific Standard Time and Pacific Daylight Time, regardless of whether those were applicable in the other time zone.

This illustrates the time zone limitations of the `Date` object.  The `moment` object does not have such limitations.

Lastly, if you are writing a new application targeting only modern browsers or Node.js, the Moment team recommends using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) instead.  Its time zone support is provided by the environment rather than data files, so it is much smaller.

Comment: Thanks for clearing out the moment object creation. It has simplified my code a lot.

About using Luxon I will give it a try. Thanks,